# give variables in an array the value of variables in another array

Tags: arrays, sas

So, I have a range of sas dates (18141 to 18414) and a range of id numbers (m101-m254). I want to have every value in the date range appear once for every value in the id range such that

```
date  id
18141 m101
18142 m101
18143 m101
..    ..
18414 m102
18141 m102
18142 m102
18143 m102
..    ..
18414 m102
```

etc

I have been trying this:

```
data data;
array linx (274) d18141-d18414;
array ids(154) m101-m254;
retain d18141-d18414 m101-m254;
do i=1 to 274;
do j=1 to 154;
linx(i)=ids(j);
end;
end;
run;
```

but sas just sticks the two arrays together side-by-side. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation of your data doesn't exactly make sense.  If this were an excel sheet, what would it look like?  Is `d18141` a variable or a value?

Comment: *fixed the example of what I am looking for*

Comment: In c+* you can simply do this int array[][];

Comment: I only really know how to use SAS, and R sort of . . .?

Comment: SAS arrays are nothing like c++ arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays aren't really the right way to handle this.  Arrays are across a single row; you're doing this with rows, not columns.

A plain old do loop will do this for you, with the `output` statement.

```
data want;
do id_n=101 to 254;
  do date='18141'd to '18414'd;
    id=cats('m',id_n);
    output;
  end;
end;
run;
```

Comment: You are a super genius. Thanks!